# Why are the entropies of magnitude and squared magnitude of Gaussian/normal vector different?

Tags: random-variable, information-theory, mutual-information, multivariate-normal-distribution

I consider a circular complex normal variable $x = x_r + i x_i \sim \mathcal{CN}(0, \sigma^2)$. I know that the PDFs of the magnitude $r$ of that variable and the squared magnitude $s = r^2$ are given by a Rayleigh distribution $f(r;\sigma) = \frac{x}{\sigma^2} e^{-x^2/(2\sigma^2)}$ and exponential distribution $f(s,\sigma) = \frac{1}{2\sigma^2}e^{-s/(2\sigma^2)}$, respectively (c.f. for example http://www.randomservices.org/random/special/Rayleigh.html).

Now, if I look at the entropies of these PDFs (wiki) I find that they scale with $\log(\sigma)$ and $\log(\sigma^2)$. Here, I do not care about terms that do not depend on $\sigma$.

**How can this difference be explained intuitively?** In my intuition both representations should carry the same Shannon information as they are just different representations of the same quantity, completely characterized by $\sigma$. Note that - in general - a difference of two entropies will not absorb the scaling: $\log(\sigma_1)-\log(\sigma_2)\neq \log(\sigma_1^2)-\log(\sigma_2^2)$. Hence, also mutual information would scale differently with $\sigma$. As far as I know mutual information is supposed to be invariant under coordinate transformation.

Comment: the question is also related to that one: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/233711/invariance-of-mutual-information-two-dimensional-gaussian